# Error while passing prop from parent to child - type is invalid

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, babeljs

I know there are a lot of similar questions to this on this site but none of them matches my code so I can not understand them as I am completely new to React JS. Basically I am making a dice application. I have created a class for number of sides and number of dice separately and I am trying to pass number of sides and number of dice from both classes into another class where I will calculate the maximum score possible -> Number of dice * Number of sides. When I pass number of sides into child class, it is successful, however when I pass number of dice, It gives me the error:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

EDIT: finally got it. it had nothing to do with the classes itself, I was rendering NoOfDice class before the child class

Comment: Show how you import the child component in both

Comment: This is most common with incorrect imports. Named vs Default, wrong relative path, etc.

Comment: this is all i have. I don't import or anything. I don't even know how to do that

Comment: Are all three components located in the same file?

Comment: @LuckyGrewal You must be importing your child class to other components?

Comment: Yes. all three components are in same file

Comment: I just put this code into a snippet and it ran with no errors. There must be something else going on not present in the question.

Comment: Please tell me if you need me to post anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code you posted as demonstrated below

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.noOfSides}</h1>
        <h1>{this.props.noOfDice}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class NoOfDice extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { mystate: 1 };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Number of Dice</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.mystate}</h2>
        <Child noOfDice={this.state.mystate} /> //error is
        in this line
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<NoOfDice />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Child expects noOfDice as the props, that's why it works in one scenario and not the other. You should keep the name same.
I've edited your code with prop name as `acceptedNumber`.
Also check Child component has been properly imported.

Try this:

```
// NoOfSides
class NoOfSides extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { mystate: 6 };
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>
      <h1>Number of Sides</h1>
      <h2 >
        {this.state.mystate}
      </h2>
      <Child acceptedNumber={this.state.mystate} />
    </div>
    );
  }
};
```

```
// NoOfDice
class NoOfDice extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { mystate: 1 };
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <h1>Number of Dice</h1>
      <h2 >
        {this.state.mystate}
      </h2>
      <Child acceptedNumber={this.state.mystate} />
    </div>
    );
  }
};
```

```
// Child
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.acceptedNumber}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: And how do you differentiate if its no of sides or no of dice?

Comment: You can have another prop named as "parentName". Pass "NoOfSides" and "NoOfDice" respectively. Do you want me to include that too the solution ?

Comment: @BrianThompson your argument makes sense. That's why I asked the OP to check if Component is imported properly

Comment: The OP claims they are all within the same file, which would mean no chance of an incorrect import, although that was my first guess too.